# Contract deployment - Error URI Too Long

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

I was trying to deploy a smart contract using the remix IDE. Everything was working fine and suddenly I started getting this error. Spent a couple hours solving it. No luck! Is this an issue with the Metamask or Remix IDE? The code has been working fine on the network for a couple of weeks (no change made).

[image: Screenshot of the error]

EDIT: The error has vanished and normal behavior has resumed.

Comment: Suddenly getting exactly the same error with Remix. I am trying to push to the Ropsten test network

Comment: I have the same problem. Deploi works normally on small contracts. But I have 1200 lines and I get the same error

Comment: Same, getting this error with the injected web3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I guess its either Chrome browser's problem or the chrome version of metamask. I tried to use remix in firefox with metamask and it works like a charm. I am still facing the same issue with chrome. This is not exactly a solution but a workaround for now.

Since there is no update for 24 hours I will raise this as an issue in metamask github and update with any solution I find.

EDIT: This was indeed an issue with the new update metamask rolled. It was reported and fixed [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3030).

Answer (score 2):

i get same wrong,i had solved this question, at settings, behind compile, rum ,you we you should setting the `Enable Optimization` [image]

Comment: enabling or disabling the optimization option doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Strange, but this worked for me.